# island count two-dimensional array algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
let arr = [[1, 0, 1],
           [1, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 1]
     ];
```

i have array where 1-island and 0-water. I need to write a island counter. Here are 2 island 1 big and 1 small(singele). For example here are 5 single islands

```
let arr = [[1, 0, 1],
           [0, 1, 0],
           [1, 0, 1]
     ];
```

i had write double cycle to appeal each item in array like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(let x = 0; x < arr[i].length; x++){
         if(...){}
    }
 }
```

and I need to write сondition for this. Help me please.

Comment: what is the wanted result? the count of islands? the size?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to write. I need count of islands

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which kind of "condition" are you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a counter and check all adjacent items and update the element with the actual counter.

```js
function check(array) {

    function test(array, i, j, value) {
        if (array[i] && array[i][j] === -1) {
            array[i][j] = value;
            test(array, i -1, j, value);
            test(array, i + 1, j, value);
            test(array, i, j - 1, value);
            test(array, i, j + 1, value);
            return true;
        }
    }
    var value = 1;

    array.forEach(a=> a.forEach((b, i, bb) => bb[i] = -b));
    array.forEach((a, i, aa) => a.forEach((b, j) => test(aa, i, j, value) && value++));
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += array.map(a => a.join(' ')).join('\n') + '<hr>';
    return value - 1;
}

console.log(check([[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]));
console.log(check([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]));
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I loved this question. It's a fundamental one. So deserves an efficient algorithm as far as i can come up with. I think it cries for recursion.

```js
/**
 * function to resolve islands
 * @param  {Array} map     - the world map we provide
 * @param  {Array} islands - 2D array considiting of island arrays each
 *                           holding island coordinates. Defaults to []
 * @return {Array} islands - "
**/
function resolveIslands(map, islands = []){

  /**
   * function to take a coordinate and split 4 neighboring coordinates into 1s and 0s
   * @param  {Number} r - 0 indexed row value
   * @param  {Number} c - 0 indexed column value
   * @return {Array}    - coordinates of 0s and 1s split in the form of [[0s],[1s]]
  * */
  function splitRoutes(r,c){
    return [[r-1,c],[r,c-1],[r+1,c],[r,c+1]].reduce((p,[r,c]) => map[r]    === void 0 ||
                                                                 map[r][c] === void 0 ? p
                                                                                      : map[r][c] ? (p[1].push([r,c]),p)
                                                                                                  : (p[0].push([r,c]),p), [[],[]]);
  }
  
  /**
   * function to take a coordinate and solve the island if the coordinate is 1
   * @param {Number} r     - 0 index row value
   * @param {Number} c     - 0 index column value
   * @param {Array} island - An array of arrays of coordinates representing the
                             currently resolved island
   * @param {Number} oc    - The number of 1s in da hood
   * @param {Array} tz     - Gradually becoming all available zeros in the map
                             initially []
   * @return {Undefined}   - Full of side effects :)
  * */
  function scan(r, c, island = [], oc = 0, tz = []){
    var [toZeros,toOnes] = splitRoutes(r,c);
    tz.push(...toZeros);
    switch (map[r][c]) {
      case 1: !island.length && islands.push(island);
              oc += toOnes.length;
              map[r][c] = void 0;
              island.push([r,c]);
              toOnes.forEach(([r,c]) => scan(r,c,island,--oc,tz));
              !oc && tz.forEach(([r,c]) => map[r][c] === 0 && scan(r,c,island,oc,tz));
              break;
      case 0: map[r][c] = void 0;
              toOnes.forEach(([r,c]) => map[r][c] === 1 && scan(r,c));
              tz.forEach(([r,c]) => map[r][c] === 0 && scan(r,c));
              break;
    }
  }
  scan(0,0);
  return islands;
}



let arr = [[1, 0, 1],
           [1, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 1]
          ],
    brr = [[1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
           [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
           [1, 0, 1 ,1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
           [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
          ];

console.log(JSON.stringify(resolveIslands(arr)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(resolveIslands(brr)));
```

The `primaryRoutes(r,c)` utility function takes a coordinate and returns the routes we can visit next in an array. The routes holding 1s are prioritized, routes with 0s are retarded (put at the back of the queue) and the ones either out of map or the zeroes visited previously are neglected.

Every visited cell becomes `void 0` which is a perfect `undefined`.

This is slightly slower than the accepted answer but I still think it's efficient considering you get the island coordinates as well. So in order to get the count of the found islands you have the check the `length` property of the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

A more verbose answer which is much easier to follow:

```
function gridToList(grid, rows, column){
  var lg = [];
  var gridString = "<p>";
  for(var z = 0; z < grid.length; z++){
    gridString = gridString.concat("[");
    gridString = gridString.concat(grid[z]);
    lg = lg.concat(grid[z]);
    gridString = gridString.concat("]<br/>");
    gridString = gridString.concat("</p>");
  }
  var el = document.getElementById("initialData");
  if(el){
      el.innerHTML = "rows:" + rows + "<br>" +
    "column:" + column + "<br>" +
    "grid:" + gridString + "<br>";
  }
  return lg
}

function numberAmazonGoStores(rows, column, grid)
{
  var idm = {};

  lg = gridToList(grid, rows, column);

  for(var z = 0; z < lg.length; z++){
    if(lg[z]){
      idm[z] = 1;
    }
  }

  var findNeighbors = function(b) {

    var currentBuilding = parseInt(b);
    var currRow = Math.floor(currentBuilding/column);

    //remove value from map so we dont re-traverse it.
    delete idm[currentBuilding];

    var u,d,l,r;

    // u = - column if > 0
    u = currentBuilding - column;
    if(idm[u]) {
      findNeighbors(u);
    }

    // d = + column if < column*rows
    d = currentBuilding + column;
    if(idm[d]) {
      findNeighbors(d);
    }

    // l = - 1 if > 0 && same row;
    l = currentBuilding - 1;
    var lRow = Math.floor(l/column);
    if(lRow === currRow && idm[l]) {
      findNeighbors(l);
    }

    // r = + 1 if < row && same row;
    r = currentBuilding + 1;

    var rRow = Math.floor(r/column);
    if(rRow === currRow && idm[r]) {
      findNeighbors(r);
    }
  }

  var clusters = 0;
  // loop over non traversed values in map
  for(p in idm){
    if(idm[p]){
      findNeighbors(p);
    }
    clusters += 1;
  }
  console.log("grid size = " + lg.length);
  console.log("total clusters found: " + clusters)
  return clusters;
}

g = [
[1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,1]
]
numberAmazonGoStores(4,4,g);

g2 = [
[1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1],
[0,1,0,0,0],
[1,0,1,1,0],
[0,1,0,0,1],
[1,0,1,0,1],
[0,1,0,1,0]
];
numberAmazonGoStores(7,5,g2);
```

Comment: what is the specific algorithm for solving the problem?

Comment: It's only more verbose when you're in a browser

Comment: @NinaScholz I would call this a recursive dept first search. Here is a small snippet from the internet:
Traversing a graph. ... You can do this easily by iterating through all the vertices of the graph, performing the algorithm on each vertex that is still unvisited when examined. Two algorithms are generally used for the traversal of a graph: Depth first search (DFS) and Breadth first search (BFS).

Comment: @LucaKiebel I say its more verbose mainly because I don't have nested loops or chained operations. instead I made sure each logical part was broken out on separate lines to readers could walk thru the logic easier. The logging and ui update is just diet frosting for those that want to quickly copy, paste and run.

Answer (score 0):

```
const map = [
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
];

function findIslands(arr) {
  let rows = arr.length,
    cols = arr[0].length; // matrix dimentions

  let islands = 0;
  let eaten = []; // connected islands on the latest iterations

  let left = 0, // island on the left
    up = 0; // island on the right

  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      if (!arr[row][col]) {
        continue; // skip zero (water)
      }
      left = col > 0 ?
        arr[row][col - 1] :
        0;

      up = row > 0 ?
        arr[row - 1][col] :
        0;
      if (!left && !up) { // new island starts if there is water on the left and up
        islands++;
        arr[row][col] = islands; // give a number to island 
      } else if (left && up && left !== up) { //upper island is not seperate
        arr[row][col] = left;
        eaten.push(up)
      } else if (left) {
        arr[row][col] = left; // island continues previous island to the right
      } else if (up) {
        arr[row][col] = up; // island continues previous island
      }
    }
  }
  console.table(arr)
  return islands - eaten.length;
}

console.log('найдено островов ', findIslands(map))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it